# Changing components state from a function in another file

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm quite new in React and I don't really understand how to make this work. I'm trying to update App.js's user state with the information coming from MediaAPI.js. I've tried to create a method in App component and then call the method from MediaAPI.js with the JSON data in brackets, but it really isn't working. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    user: [],
  };


  updateUser = (data) => {
    this.setState({user: data});
  };


  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Nav/>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
              <Route exact path="/home" render={(props) => (
                  <Home {...props} picArray={this.state.picArray}/>
              )}/>
              <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
              <Route exact path="/single/:id" component={Single}/>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

MediaAPI.js

```
import App from '../App';

  const login = (username, password) => {
  return fetch(loginUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({username, password})
  }).then(response => response.json()).then(json=> {
    console.log(json);
    App.updateUser(json);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way `App.updateUser(json);` only work when your method is static, and in a static method, you don't have access to `this`, there are ways to achieve this:

## 1:

you can use your login function inside you App component like this :

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    user: [],
  };

  login = (username, password) => {
    return fetch(loginUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({username, password})
    }).then(response => response.json()).then(data=> {
       this.setState({user: data});
    });
  };


  componentDidMount(data){
    this.login('username', 'password');
  };


  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Nav/>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
              <Route exact path="/home" render={(props) => (
                  <Home {...props} picArray={this.state.picArray}/>
              )}/>
              <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
              <Route exact path="/single/:id" component={Single}/>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

### note:

and also you can simplify the login method by using Async/await like this :

```
  login = async (username, password) => {
    const response =  await fetch(loginUrl,
         { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({username, password})
    });
    const user =  await response.json();
    this.setState({ user });
  };
```

### note:

and also you can do like this:

```
import { login } from 'MediaAPI.js';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    user: [],
  };

  async componentDidMount(data){
    const user = await login('username', 'password');
    this.setState({ user });
  };


  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Nav/>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
              <Route exact path="/home" render={(props) => (
                  <Home {...props} picArray={this.state.picArray}/>
              )}/>
              <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
              <Route exact path="/single/:id" component={Single}/>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

MediaAPI.js

```
   export const login = (username, password) => {
      return fetch(loginUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({username, password})
      }).then(response => response.json());
    };
```

## 2:

you can create a component and on that component use App and set ref to it and then use `updateUser` method.

---- there are other ways but I think those two are best.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, I'd argue your approach is an anti-pattern. Below is how I'd approach it.

```
import mediaAPI from 'MediaAPI'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    user: [],
  };

  // this is a React lifecycle hook that will be
  // called when the component has mounted.
  componentDidMount() {
    mediaAPI()
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(this.setUserData)
  }


  setUserData = (data) => {
    this.setState({user: data});
  };


  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Nav/>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
              <Route exact path="/home" render={(props) => (
                  <Home {...props} picArray={this.state.picArray}/>
              )}/>
              <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
              <Route exact path="/single/:id" component={Single}/>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}
```